# Droping observations take takes place in the same place (longiture and latitude)

Tags: r, spatial

So I have a big Dataframe, that in order to apply spatial econometrics modeling I need to create weights matrix

When trying K-near-neighbours in `spdep` and using command like:

```
nb_cord <- cbind(df_model$longitude, df_model$latitude)

nb_cord_5NN <- knearneigh(nb_cord, k = 5, longlat = TRUE)
```

I get:

```
Error in knearneigh(nb_cord, k = 5, longlat = TRUE) : 
  too many ties in knearneigh
In addition: Warning message:
In knearneigh(nb_cord, k = 5, longlat = TRUE) :
  knearneigh: identical points found
```

How would I elimine exatly same longtitude and latitude observations from `df_model`

Comment: class packages knn() function breaks identical distance problems by randomly selecting one of them's classes. it may be useful for you